# nlapiSenEmail API is Not sending email in Scheduled Script

Tags: javascript, email, netsuite

Am new to netsuite development. I have created a suitescript of scheduled script type. In that i use the following code

```
nlapiSendEmail(473882, 'yoursfred@yahoo.in','Test','Test', null, null, null);
```

The above code is sending email at the time of debuggin using Netsuite Script Debugger.
When we create scheduled record and deployed the same code and scheduled for testing it is not sending the code and not even shows any errors. Can anyone help in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also are you testing this in your sandbox account?  Sandbox accounts have limitations in sending out emails.

Comment: Yes.. As the sandbox didnt allow you to send the email real time for limtations

Comment: for what it is worth, there is a setting in Email Settings that allow sandbox emails to be sent out to the current user. The subject of the email will append a line indicating the intended recipient: "[SANDBOX] your subject here (originally To: blahblah@gmail.com)"

Took me a while to figure out why I was getting emails on my work email when I was pointing the script towards my gmail :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of schedule script. Make sure the script is running as Administrator role.

Alternatively run the script from the same user as the from parameter of the function. **473882** in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the "problem" was that I was just working in the Sandbox, as I prepared a snippet to test email sending in production everything went right.